# External Object in Lightning error: "Unsupported Item"

Tags: lightning, lightning-connect, salesforce-connect, externalobjects

I am currently developing a custom Apex adapter for Salesforce Connect. In Classic, the external object record is loading successfully from the external source.

When I load the record in Lightning, on the other hand, I receive the error: "You can't view this item in Lightning Experience. Open in Salesforce Classic." Additionally, the tab title reads "Unsupported Item".

The only limitation with Lightning that I have found for external objects is needing to disable "High Data Volume", which has been done for the external data source. This is defined here: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=platform_connect_considerations_lex.htm&type=5

Is there anything else that I need to activate for external objects to appear in Lightning?

Comment: is this in console app?

Comment: Yes it is in service console, but I receive the same error in LEX Sales app as well. The error is now happening inconsistently, where now I can't reproduce the error every time I load an external object's record page and the external objects display as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue before and was able to resolve by going to the Lightning App Builder and creating a record page for the external object which I then added to my app. I think I also has to assign the page as the org default (or at least to my profile).