Not able to list records from an External Object in Lightning Tab, but the same list is visible in Classic Tab
I stumbled upon this and spent a lot of time searching answers but found nothing promising.
Let me set a context first, I'm using an External Data Source which responds following the OData 4.0 protocol. (URL: https://services.odata.org/TripPinRESTierService/(S(oyttwdxyic3om2megsa3ywts) )
I'm able to add the Data Source, I'm able to create three objects and I'm able to Query the data in Query Editor and all the basic out of the box stuff.


Post this, I created a Custom Object Tab for one of these objects (say Airport object).

When I try to navigate to "Airports" Item in App Launcher, the tab opens but with an error message "You can't view this item in Lightning Experience.
Open in Salesforce Classic."

Upon navigating to the Classic link provided here in this message, I see the data, at least the default list view with DisplayURL.

I'm able to build custom LWC components wire a controller and view the data.
My question is, I don't know if I missed some documentation or some literature, if salesforce can fetch and show list of data on Classic, why is it not able to render on lightning even though the tab is accessible in Lightning.
I'm using only one user, that is also on System Administrator Profile.
I'm just junior developer and curious to know more...since I couldn't find any literature, I'm posting a question here seeking guidance.
Any suggestion and guidance are appreciated, Thanks in advance
UPDATE: I removed the data source and added it again, Now I'm able to see the data in the lightning experience.

Can you refer to this post: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/213152/external-object-in-lightning-error-unsupported-item
